# How to convert a python print function on html

Tags: python-2.7, web2py

I am trying to use web2py to build an app. I have a simple print function that a user submits a key word . The string or int key word  is directed to an sqlite db to retrieve a row and output the data. I need to know 
1. how to use the print on html. 
2. How to split the string...so far i did the list:string

Here is my code:

```
def first():
    form = SQLFORM.factory(Field('visitor_name',
                                 label = 'Please Type Your keyword here!',
                                 requires= [IS_NOT_EMPTY(), IS_LOWER(),'list:string']))
    form.element('input[type=submit]')['_onclick'] = "return \
    confirm('Are you sure you want to submit:');"
    if form.process().accepted:
        session.visitor_name = form.vars.visitor_name        
        redirect(URL('main'))
    return dict(form=form)


def main():    
    while True:
        name = request.vars.visitor_name or redirect(URL('first'))          
        name2 = name[:]        
        for item in name2:break
        name3 = ' '.join(name2)
        import sqlite3
        id = 0
        location = ""
        conn = sqlite3.connect("keywords.db")
        c = conn.cursor()
        c.execute('select * from kmedicals')
        records = c.fetchall()
        for record in records:
            id = record[0]
            location = record[15]
            if id == name3:
                print name3.capitalize(),':' '\n',location
                break
                sys.exit()
        return dict(name=name)
```

my view...default/main.html:

```
{{extend 'layout.html'}}
{{=name}}
```

Comment: You say "The string or int key word is iterated to an sqlite db", why are you iterating?  Please explain more clearly what you are trying to do.

Comment: meant directed, sorry for the mistype

Comment: What Problems are you having with the regular print statement?

Comment: i cant see the print output from the db nor can i get any error. Is there some code i need to use on the : print name3.capitalize(),':' '\n',location ??

Comment: It doesn't look like you're using web2py properly.  IMO you should read the documentation a little more or a tutorial.  Web2py has Database abstraction layer which you can use.  For example your controller could look like this: `def example():
    records = 
SQLTABLE(db(db.kmedicals.some_field.contains(keyword)).select())
    return dict(records=records)`